# How do I configure Mavensmate/Sublime to allow me to edit and save to server Lightning/Aura Components?

Tags: lightning, mavensmate, sublime

I'm trying to move over to Sublime from the developer console. I have MavensMate installed and already use it to edit apex code and custom objects. When I am editing this code, ctrl+s always automatically saves it to the server.

However, now that I'm trying to develop Lightning components, I'm not able to deploy it to the server. The "deploy to server" option is unavailable and when I try to "Force Save Active File" I get the following error:

**Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: local variable 'meta_type' referenced before assignment**

My package.xml file contains the following:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
     <members>*</members>
     <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
</types>
<version>34.0</version>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there any special handling I need to set up to develop on lightning within Sublime, or is it a bug?

Comment: Do you have mavensmate v7?

Comment: Am running v6. Will try updating- thanks!

Comment: Getting started with Lightning and the "AuraDefinitionBundle" was a nice tip to be able to view the schema structure related to Lightning development.

Answer (score 7):

As posted in the README notes, you must update to version 7:

#### Version 7 [prerelease channel]

**You must install the following before continuing:**

1. Sublime Text 3 http://www.sublimetext.com/3
2. Sublime Text Package Control https://packagecontrol.io/installation
3. MavensMate-app **(must be running in order for MavensMate for Sublime Text v7.0+ to function)** https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate-app/releases

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** In order to install the v7 betas, you must add `"MavensMate"` to your Package Control `"install_prereleases"` user setting, see below:

[image: screen shot 2015-09-02 at 9 10 17 am]
[image: package_control_sublime-settings_ _df15-react-communities-ios]
[image: screen shot 2015-10-12 at 12 53 39 pm]